# Defining a custom route in a namespaced api in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have created a namespaced api in my rails 5 project. I have the following in my config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'api_user_token' => 'api_user_token#create'
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :events
    end
  end
end
```

Events Controller

```
module Api::V1
  class EventsController < ApiController
     #Code here
  end
end
```

API Controller

```
   module Api::V1
     class ApiController < ApplicationController
       before_action :authenticate_api_user
       respond_to :json

       def register
       end  
     end
   end
```

I want the **'/api/v1/register'** route to go to the **register method** defined in my api controller. How can i define the route in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :events
    post :register, to: 'apis#register'
  end
end
```

This will generate

```
api_v1_register POST  /api/v1/register(.:format)  api/v1/apis#register
```